# How to write a makeFile to install primme and slepc?

Tags: c, makefile, petsc

I want to execute multiple files and two libraries (primme and slepc) using my makeFile. My makeFile looks like :

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc

# Directories
SLEPC_DIR = /home/student/Documents/projet/codeProjet17SLEPc/CodePub/slepc-3.20.1
PRIMME_DIR = /home/student/Documents/projet/codeProjet17SLEPc/CodePub/primme

# SLEPc settings
include ${SLEPC_DIR}/lib/slepc/conf/slepc_common
SLEPC_INC = -I${SLEPC_DIR}/include

# PRIMME settings
PRIMME_LIB = -L${PRIMME_DIR} -lprimme
PRIMME_INC = -I${PRIMME_DIR}/PRIMMESRC/COMMONSRC

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS = -g -Wall $(SLEPC_CCFLAGS)

# Linker flags
LDFLAGS = $(SLEPC_EPS_LIB) -lm -lblas -llapack

# Targets
TARGET = executable
SOURCES = main.c prob.c time.c interface_primme.c graph.c res.c temp.c diff.c # Add your source files here
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

# Build rules
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(PRIMME_LIB) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(SLEPC_INC) $(PRIMME_INC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

I followed the documentation of slepc. The documentation ask to write a makeFile of the form :

```
default: ex1
include ${SLEPC_DIR}/lib/slepc/conf/slepc_common
ex1: ex1.o
    -${CLINKER} -o ex1 ex1.o ${SLEPC_EPS_LIB}
     ${RM} ex1.o
```

However, I still encounter the same problem constantly : I get the error " Makefile:36: *** target file 'clean' has both : and :: entries.  Stop. " I do not know how to overcome this problem ...

I tried to execute my program without using the splec_common (this file points to multiple others and I feel like it may give some clean information which cause the problem). Nonetheless, then using the library become difficult.... I do not have a lot of experience in makeFile writing, so if any body could help my with that I would be grateful

Comment: The problem is that you define a rule `clean:` (single-colon rule) but somewhere there's also a rule `clean::` (double-colon rule).  Since we don't see it here, it's probably in the included makefile `${SLEPC_DIR}/lib/slepc/conf/slepc_common`.  One simple way to fix it is to change your clean target to be double-colon as well, by writing it as `clean::`

Comment: @MadScientist In fact, it resolved the first issue. However, I do not get any .o file. My code does not show any error but my debbuger does not display either. When I want to run the main file I get "bash: ./main: No such file or directory". Do you have any idea of what I could do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Not with the information provided.  Did you look at the output printed by make when it runs?  Did it try to build your files?  If it didn't then clearly they won't be there and you can't run them.  My suspicion is that you should move the `all:` target up above the `include` line, or else run `make all` to force that target to be built.  Make always builds the first defined target in the makefile by default (if you don't specify a target on the command line) and if you put the `include` before any of your targets then the default will be the first target in the `include` file.

Comment: I moved the all : above the include

Comment: My code compiled but I got an error " In file included from /home/student/Documents/projet/codeProjet17SLEPc/CodePub/slepc-3.20.1/include/slepcst.h:16,
                 from /home/student/Documents/projet/codeProjet17SLEPc/CodePub/slepc-3.20.1/include/slepceps.h:16,
                 from interfaceSlepc.c:5:
/home/student/Documents/projet/codeProjet17SLEPc/CodePub/slepc-3.20.1/include/slepcsys.h:17:10: fatal error: petscsys.h: No such file or directory
   17 | #include <petscsys.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:39: interfaceSlepc.o] Error 1"

Comment: I tested my library installation with the tests provided. It works well so I assume that my library is configured correctly with petsc. So, I think that this error comes from my makefiles

Comment: Look at the compile line that make printed.  The error is it can't find that header.  Look at that header, compare the path of that header to the `-I` options on the compile line make is running.  There's really nothing we can to do help you because we can't see your environment and where everything is.  There's no magic: the compiler simply appends the filename to each of the directories provided with `-I` and tries to read them.  That error seems like maybe you have a permissions problem or a bad symlink or something even.